# Parse, Swift and Xcode 6.1 - cannot create PFObject subclass by calling .object()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode6.1

Today I updated Xcode to 6.1 and my Parse project stopped compiling.
I use Swift. 
I have a `Post` class declared as `class Post: PFObject, PFSubclassing` with custom properties.

When I try to call something like: `var post = Post.object()` Xcode says `.object() is unavailable: use object construction PFObject()` and stops compiling.

I updated cocoapods and use Parse 1.4.2 SDK version. I also performed Clean build and removed Derived Data.
It looks like subclassing is somehow broken.

Everything worked fine yesterday on Xcode 6.0.1.

[image]

Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Try this var post:PFObject = Post.Object()

Comment: @walle84 it doesn't work: `Post.Type does not have a member called Object`.

Temporarily fixed by following Xcode suggestion:
`var post = Post()` <-- just simple costructor
but it's not advised in `PFObject+Subclassing.h` documentation for `+ (instancetype)object;` method.

Comment: Parse team confirmed it's a [valid bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/349654705211582)

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround, you may use `Post(className: "Post")`. However, this forces you to provide class name every time.

But at least it compiles.